# Difference between sklearn make_pipeline and imblearn make_pipeline

Tags: predictive-modeling, pandas, class-imbalance, pipelines, imbalanced-learn

Can anybody please explain the difference between `sklearn.pipeline.make_pipline` and `imblearn.pipeline.make_pipline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`imblearn`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package contains a lot of different samplers for easy over- or under-sampling of data.
These samplers can not be placed in a standard sklearn pipeline.

To allow for using a pipeline with these samplers, the `imblearn` package also implements an extended pipeline. This pipeline is very similar to the `sklearn` one with the addition of allowing samplers.

*If you want to include samplers in the pipeline, use the `imblearn` pipeline. Otherwise, use the `sklearn` one.*

---

The code for the imblearn pipeline can be seen [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/pipeline.py) and the sklearn pipeline code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/pipeline.py). Note that `make_pipeline` is just a convenient method to create a new pipeline and the differnece here is actually with the pipelines themselves.

Comment: but why is a sampler not implemented using the fit/transform paradigm of sklearn? what's different about this?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan: Without any deeper investigation, it could be due to the different treatment of training and testing data (see e.g. https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/547#issuecomment-451115193) or due to the issue that data is added or removed in the sampler which the standard `sklearn` API maybe doesn't support (since there is no need to).

Comment: In case someone wants to understand more about Samplers, I found this article useful: https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-oversampling-and-undersampling-for-imbalanced-classification/